# Inserting data in NHibernate but not interested in identifier

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm getting data from a webserver and insert them in my PostgreSQL database.
My table has an id as `serial`, which is an auto-increment value handled by a sequence in PostgreSQL.

I'm just inserting data and don't do anything with the data after that point.
So I'm not interested in the value of the ID.
I see that NHibernate is calling `select nextval` for every insert.
How to tell NHibernate it is not necessary?
It just needs to send an insert-statement and move on.

In my xml I have:

```
<id name="Id" column="id">
  <generator class="native">
    <param name="sequence">id_seq</param>
  </generator>
</id>
```

I'm using this xml/class in other parts as well and then I get the data and then I do need the value of id.

Comment: i don't think this is possible. NHibernate needs this value for the insert statement. You could create the Id by yourself, then it wouldn't call `nextval`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with a stateless session?
http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/batch.html#batch-statelesssession